# Как правильно распаковать в список?

Tags: python

Нужно распаковать строку в список. Как правильно это сделать?

```
mylist = []
stroka = "abcdef"
*mylist = stroka
```

типа такого

Comment: `mylist = list(stroka)` ?

Comment: mylist.append("abcdef") @Oleg возможно этот вариант подойдёт,только не распаковать а добавить в

Comment: Да, это понятно. Я хотелось методом распаковки через * увидеть. Например:
first, *mylist = stroka будет всё, кроме первого символа, вот и подумалось, может как то скобками можно изголица, чтобы всю строку засунуть в массив.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Собственно, если внимательно прочитать сообщение об ошибке при использовании выражения

```
>>> s = "string"
>>> *l = s
  *l = s
        ^
SyntaxError: starred assignment target must be in a list or tuple
```

то можно понять, что достаточно иметь слева кортеж или список:

```
>>> *l, = s
>>> l
['s', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g']

>>> [*l] = s
>>> l
['s', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g']
```

Так как в Python во многих случаях можно создавать кортеж, используя только запятую, то `*l, = s` просто является краткой формой записи выражения `(*l, ) = s`

Comment: Спасибо. Именно это и спрашивал. Не догадался запятую после добавить :)

Answer (score 3):

К слову, в питоне вы можете работать с строками как с массивом:

```
In [2]: s = "Hello, world!"

In [3]: s[1]  # Уже почти массив!
Out[3]: 'e'

In [4]: s[1:4]
Out[4]: 'ell'

In [5]: mylist = list(s)  # Вот что вам нужно
In [6]: mylist
Out[6]: ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ',', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '!']

In [8]: type(mylist)
Out[8]: builtins.list  # Массив!

In [9]: type(s)
Out[9]: builtins.str  # Строка!
```

Comment: Вопрос был именно в использовании метода распаковки. За mylist = list(s) я в курсе.